# how to make composer require a specific php.ini property

Tags: php, composer-php

I would like to know if there is a way to make composer require that in php ini the `upload_max_filesize` is equal to 10M for example

Comment: Since that property can be configured in different places, it doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense to enforce that at the time of dependency installation…

Comment: What is your final purpose? I think you should set `php.ini` properties in other places (e.g maybe set for server requests dynamically)

Comment: Composer usually is run on the commandline - which more often than not has a DIFFERENT php.ini configuration that the web server. So this check will not guarantee smooth operation at all. Granted, it's the same situation with extensions (CLI extensions can differ from HTTP server extensions), but an extension is either there or not - it cannot have a million different values.

Answer (score 1):

Composer has no interface to check if PHP settings are in a certain state. If you want to enforce specific settings, you should check them during runtime and give an appropriate message to the developer or environment operator.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible with this type of command

```bash
php -c path/to/custom/php.ini composer.phar <command>
```

Depending on your setup, it could be necessary to give the full path to composer.phar file.

**Update**

As suggested in the comments, I'll try to add more details to my answer.

My understanding of OP question is that he is searching for a way to make sure composer runs the commands under certain conditions and properties that are set in the `php.ini` file.

The best way to make this happen without altering the current environment settings, is to provide a custom php.ini file via CLI and the option `-c` with the desired properties.

What maybe I've misinterpreted is that OP instead asks for methods a package provider can use to check if some properties/values are set during the installation process.
If this is OP request then my answer is not relevant.

Comment: Please share more details. How does that command ensure that any configuration is set to a specific value?

Comment: @NicoHaase Maybe I've misinterpreted the question, my first understanding was that OP asked for a way to use custom php.ini properties replacing what is found in the regular php.ini file. If instead is expected that composer can in some way check for the presence or value of a particular property in the reagular php.ini file, then yes my answer is incorrect. Still I do think that by providing a tailored php.ini file with required properties will accomplish basically the same task, isn't it? Am I missing something else?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If the OP asks whether Composer can require any configuration to be set, how does your answer help to resolve that?

Comment: How can not be resolved by my answer? Unless OP is asking not for using it on user side but on the package provider side? Something like while installing a package ensure that some properties are set? If that is the case isn't the question rather ambiguous by how is worded?

Comment: Feel free to add more details to your answer such that others can learn from it